# Bug not allowing users to select the third row for tic tac toe

Tags: python

As the title suggest, the bug I am running into is not allowing the first person to select the third row of my Tic Tac Toe grid. It's is behaving like that row does not exist. Perhaps I did something wrong that I do not see or I over complicated it.

Anyway, everything else works as I want it to. This is last thing I want to fix. Also, if you guys have suggestions to make my code better and more efficient please tell me. This is my first year programming.

The code that edits the grid:

```
#Edit the Tic Tac Toe grid.
def editGrid(grid, selectedRow, selectedColumn, player):
    validRow = 0
    #Determine which player is editing the
    #grid.
    if player == " X ":      
        for rows in grid:
            #Determine which row was selected.
            if selectedRow - 1 == validRow:
                #Determine what to do based on the column selected.
                if selectedColumn == 1:
                    #Check to see if a player is in the spot selected.
                    if grid[selectedRow - 1][selectedColumn] == " O " or grid[selectedRow - 1][selectedColumn] == " X ":
                        print("\nA player is already there.")
                    else:
                        rows.insert(selectedColumn, player)
                        rows.pop(selectedColumn + 1)
                elif selectedColumn == 2:
                    if grid[selectedRow - 1][selectedColumn + 1] == " O " or grid[selectedRow - 1][selectedColumn + 1] == " X ":
                        print("\nA player is already there.")
                    else:
                        rows.insert(selectedColumn + 1, player)
                        rows.pop(selectedColumn + 2)
                elif selectedColumn == 3:
                    if grid[selectedRow - 1][selectedColumn + 2] == " O " or grid[selectedRow - 1][selectedColumn + 2] == " X ":
                        print("\nA player is already there.")
                    else:
                        rows.insert(selectedColumn + 2, player)
                        rows.pop(selectedColumn + 3)
            validRow = grid.index(rows) + 1
    else:
        for rows in grid:
            #Determine which row was selected.
            if selectedRow - 1 == validRow:
                #Determine what to do based on the column selected.
                if selectedColumn == 1:
                    #Check to see if a player is in the spot selected.
                    if grid[selectedRow - 1][selectedColumn] == " X " or grid[selectedRow - 1][selectedColumn] == " O ":
                        print("\nA player is already there.")
                    else:
                        rows.insert(selectedColumn, player)
                        rows.pop(selectedColumn + 1)
                elif selectedColumn == 2:
                    if grid[selectedRow - 1][selectedColumn + 1] == " X " or grid[selectedRow - 1][selectedColumn + 1] == " O ":
                        print("\nA player is already there.")
                    else:
                        rows.insert(selectedColumn + 1, player)
                        rows.pop(selectedColumn + 2)
                elif selectedColumn == 3:
                    if grid[selectedRow - 1][selectedColumn + 2] == " X " or grid[selectedRow - 1][selectedColumn + 2] == " O ":
                        print("\nA player is already there.")
                    else:    
                        rows.insert(selectedColumn + 2, player)
                        rows.pop(selectedColumn + 3)
            validRow = grid.index(rows) + 1
```

Side Note: I have ran the debugger and for the first time this code runs the variable "validRow" gets reset to 0 but when there is already an " X " on the grid the variable does not get reset to 0. I am genuinely confused as to why this happens.

[Here's the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy2P6.png)

Edit: Here is the rest of the code.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3

#Create the grid.
def drawGrid(grid):
    #Show the grid to the user.
    for rows in grid:
        print("+---+---+---+")
        #Print each item in the row.
        for row in rows:
            print(row, end='')
        #Formatting
        print()
    print("+---+---+---+")

#Edit the Tic Tac Toe grid.
def editGrid(grid, selectedRow, selectedColumn, player):
    validRow = 0
    #Determine which player is editing the
    #grid.
    if player == " X ":      
        for rows in grid:
            #Determine which row was selected.
            if selectedRow - 1 == validRow:
                #Determine what to do based on the column selected.
                if selectedColumn == 1:
                    #Check to see if a player is in the spot selected.
                    if grid[selectedRow - 1][selectedColumn] == " O " or grid[selectedRow - 1][selectedColumn] == " X ":
                        print("\nA player is already there.")
                    else:
                        rows.insert(selectedColumn, player)
                        rows.pop(selectedColumn + 1)
                elif selectedColumn == 2:
                    if grid[selectedRow - 1][selectedColumn + 1] == " O " or grid[selectedRow - 1][selectedColumn + 1] == " X ":
                        print("\nA player is already there.")
                    else:
                        rows.insert(selectedColumn + 1, player)
                        rows.pop(selectedColumn + 2)
                elif selectedColumn == 3:
                    if grid[selectedRow - 1][selectedColumn + 2] == " O " or grid[selectedRow - 1][selectedColumn + 2] == " X ":
                        print("\nA player is already there.")
                    else:
                        rows.insert(selectedColumn + 2, player)
                        rows.pop(selectedColumn + 3)
            validRow = grid.index(rows) + 1
    else:
        for rows in grid:
            #Determine which row was selected.
            if selectedRow - 1 == validRow:
                #Determine what to do based on the column selected.
                if selectedColumn == 1:
                    #Check to see if a player is in the spot selected.
                    if grid[selectedRow - 1][selectedColumn] == " X " or grid[selectedRow - 1][selectedColumn] == " O ":
                        print("\nA player is already there.")
                    else:
                        rows.insert(selectedColumn, player)
                        rows.pop(selectedColumn + 1)
                elif selectedColumn == 2:
                    if grid[selectedRow - 1][selectedColumn + 1] == " X " or grid[selectedRow - 1][selectedColumn + 1] == " O ":
                        print("\nA player is already there.")
                    else:
                        rows.insert(selectedColumn + 1, player)
                        rows.pop(selectedColumn + 2)
                elif selectedColumn == 3:
                    if grid[selectedRow - 1][selectedColumn + 2] == " X " or grid[selectedRow - 1][selectedColumn + 2] == " O ":
                        print("\nA player is already there.")
                    else:    
                        rows.insert(selectedColumn + 2, player)
                        rows.pop(selectedColumn + 3)
            validRow = grid.index(rows) + 1

#Determine if there are any winners.
def checkWinner(grid, player):
    if (grid[0][1] == player and grid[0][3] == player) and grid[0][5] == player:
        print("\n" + player + "wins!")
        return True
    elif (grid[1][1] == player and grid[1][3] == player) and grid[1][5] == player:
        print("\n" + player + "wins!")
        return True
    elif (grid[2][1] == player and grid[2][3] == player) and grid[2][5] == player:
        print("\n" + player + "wins!")
        return True
    elif (grid[0][1] == player and grid[1][3] == player) and grid[2][5] == player:
        print("\n" + player + "wins!")
        return True
    elif (grid[0][3] == player and grid[1][3] == player) and grid[2][3] == player:
        print("\n" + player + "wins!")
        return True
    elif (grid[0][5] == player and grid[1][5] == player) and grid[2][5] == player:
        print("\n" + player + "wins!")
        return True
    elif (grid[0][1] == player and grid[1][3] == player) and grid[2][5] == player:
        print("\n" + player + "wins!")
        return True
    elif (grid[0][5] == player and grid[1][3] == player) and grid[2][1] == player:
        print("\n" + player + "wins!")
        return True
    elif (grid[0][1] == player and grid[1][1] == player) and grid[2][1] == player:
        print("\n" + player + "wins!")
        return True
    else:
        return False

def main():
    print("Welcome to Tic Tac Toe\n")
    #Assume the user wants to play.
    userChoice = "y"
    while userChoice.lower() == "y":
        #Form the grid
        grid = [["|","   ","|", "   ","|", "   ","|"],
                ["|","   ","|", "   ","|", "   ","|"],
                ["|","   ","|", "   ","|", "   ","|"]]
        drawGrid(grid)
        #Set the default number of turns.
        numberOfTurns = 1
        isWon= False
        isTie = False
        #Run until someone wins or it ties.
        while isWon == False and isTie == False:
            #Catch any errors with the input.
            if numberOfTurns % 2 != 0:
                print("\nX's Turn")
                #Set who goes this turn and what
                #marker to use.
                player = " X "
                #Determine if all input data is valid.
                isValid = False
                while isValid == False:
                    try:
                        row = int(input("Pick a row (1, 2, 3): "))
                        #Check the validity of the input
                        #data.
                        while row < 1 or row > 3:
                            print("Please enter an integer bewteen 1 and 3. Try again.")
                            row = int(input("Pick a row (1, 2, 3): "))
                        #Ask the user which column to occupy.
                        column = int(input("Pick a column (1, 2, 3): "))
                        #Check the validity of the input
                        #data.
                        while column < 1 or column > 3:
                            print("Please enter an integer bewteen 1 and 3. Try again.")
                            column = int(input("Pick a row (1, 2, 3): "))
                        isValid = True
                        #Add the player's icon to the correct
                        #spaces.
                        editGrid(grid, row, column, player)
                    except ValueError:
                        print("Please input an integer between 1 and 3. Try again.")
                        isValid = False
            else:
                print("\nO's Turn")
                #Set who goes this turn and what
                #marker to use.
                player = " O "
                #Determine if all input data is valid.
                isValid = False
                while isValid == False:
                    try:
                        row = int(input("Pick a row (1, 2, 3): "))
                        #Check the validity of the input
                        #data.
                        while row < 1 or row > 3:
                            print("Please enter an integer bewteen 1 and 3. Try again.")
                            row = int(input("Pick a row (1, 2, 3): "))
                        #Ask the user which column to occupy.
                        column = int(input("Pick a column (1, 2, 3): "))
                        #Check the validity of the input
                        #data.
                        while column < 1 or column > 3:
                            print("Please enter an integer bewteen 1 and 3. Try again.")
                            column = int(input("Pick a row (1, 2, 3): "))
                        isValid = True
                        #Add the player's icon to the correct
                        #spaces.
                        editGrid(grid, row, column, player)
                    except ValueError:
                        print("Please input an integer between 1 and 3. Try again.")
                        isValid = False
            print()
            #Draw the edited grid.
            drawGrid(grid)
            #Determine if the programs needs to terminate.
            isWon = checkWinner(grid, player)
            #Check the status of the game.
            if isWon == False and isTie == False:
                #Keep track of how many spaces
                #are taken up.
                tokenCounter = 0
                for rows in grid:
                    for space in rows:
                        #Determine if all there spaces
                        #are taken up.
                        if space == " X " or space == " O ":
                            tokenCounter += 1
                #Determine if there was a tie.
                if tokenCounter == 9 and isWon == False:
                    isTie = True
                    print("\nIt is a tie!\n")
            #Next players goes.
            numberOfTurns += 1
        print("Round over!\n")
        userChoice = input("Do you want to play another round? (y / n) ")
        while userChoice.lower() != "y" and userChoice.lower() != "n":
            print("Please type \"y\"  or \"n\". Try again.")
            userChoice = input("Do you want to play another round? (y / n) ")
        print()
    print("\nBye!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: In the output that you linked I do not see any output from the print statements.  Why?  I don't see how the program you presented could actually run, since you try to access (for example) `grid[selectedRow-1][selectedColumn+2]` when `selectedColumn` was just verified to have a value of 3.  That means you are trying to access the *sixth* element of `grid[selectedRow-1]` which makes no sense for a 3x3 game board.  Is this really your program?

Comment: Sorry about that. I totally forgot to post the rest of the code. It's been a long few weeks. Anyway, I have to edit column 6 because of the way I made my list.                                                                                         
                                                                                                                   Edit: Those print statements should only print when there is a marker already there. If there is not a marker there, then there is no need to have them print something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are being tripped up by the `index` function.  When you call `.index(x)` on an array, it steps through the array until it finds a value equal to x.  So when you write, inside your for loop:

```
for rows in grid:
    grid.index(rows)
```

you won't necessarily get the index of `grid` that you are currently working with, but rather the first element of grid that's *equal in value* to rows.  When you have an empty board, all the rows are equal in value - so at that moment `grid.index(rows)` always returns 0.

There is a good way to fix that, but it involves rethinking how your program is structured.  In general your code is painful to read and the program is much longer and less efficient than it could be.  I strongly recommend posting it to the site CodeReview.stackexchange.com to get help with improving your approach.

Here is the portion of the program starting with `if player == " X "`.  I have eliminated the for loop entirely and replaced your insert/pop pairs with simple assignment statements.

```
if player == " X ":
    row = grid[selectedRow-1]
    #Determine what to do based on the column selected.
    if selectedColumn == 1:
        #Check to see if a player is in the spot selected.
        if row[selectedColumn] == " O " or row[selectedColumn] == " X ":
            print("\nA player is already there.")
        else:
            row[selectedColumn] = player
    elif selectedColumn == 2:
        if row[selectedColumn + 1] == " O " or row[selectedColumn + 1] == " X ":
            print("\nA player is already there.")
        else:
            row[selectedColumn+1] = player
    elif selectedColumn == 3:
        if row[selectedColumn + 2] == " O " or row[selectedColumn + 2] == " X ":
            print("\nA player is already there.")
        else:
            row[selectedColumn+2] = player
```